# Appropriate wall controller for two fans

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I'm preparing to install two ceiling fans in an especially large room.  Prefer that they both operate from a single switch.

Fans are [Tidal Breeze 56 inch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Tidal-Breeze-56-in-LED-Indoor-White-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote-Control-54663/300662514) , 0.52 amps per fan in high.  I thought I'd use the Lutron CTFSQ-F-WH controller, which matches other switches in this room.  Rated for 1.5 amps, and obviously 2*0.52<1.5.  But the manufacturer's description repeatedly emphasizes using this switch on only a single fan.  Is this likely to work?

I see that Lutron also sells a digital fan controller with a canopy module, MA-FQ4FM-W. That's rated for up to four fans, via four separate canopy modules.  But it feels overly complicated to have canopy modules when I'm running new 14/3 romex with separate fan and light power.  Cost not insubstantial -- seems to be $200+ for one wall switch plus two canopy modules.  Such cramped space to install canopy modules.  Most of all, the appearance of that switch wouldn't match others we're installing.  So I'm trying to find an alternative that works with a more traditional wall switch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If Lutron says it won't work, then it doesn't seem likely to work. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What all do you need for functionality from this controller?

Comment: While I agree that having both fans controlled by one switch makes logical sense, you may want to rethink this. For the current use case, this may be ideal, but in the future you may use the room differently (rearranging furniture, etc.) and it may no longer make sense to have both fans running at the same speed, but you'd be stuck if you didn't have an option. You may find that even with the current arrangement, you want more air flow in one place and less in another. I know that as a contact lens wearer, too much airflow will really dry out my eyes. You may want to think of guests, too.

Comment: Also, welcome to [diy.se]! Very well done for your first question here!!

Comment: ThreePhasEel, I was hoping for on-off plus some speed control such as high-medium-low.  Clear that a standard switch could give me on-off control, but I'd lose control of all intermediate speeds which would be a disappointment.

Comment: FreeMan, I see what you mean about multiple regions and potential benefits of multiple switches.  This room already has six can lights, on one switch of course, and to me two fans on a single switch made sense as the logical equivalent to that.  The room is big but it's actually outdoors (a porch) and I would not be considering two separate switches were it not for the apparent difficulty of one switch controlling both fans.